# How can I disable a label when the IE download window appears?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, internet-explorer-9

I have an ASP.NET WebForm.

When users click on a link, it calls another page. That page, in turn, references an assembly and initiates a download, which takes some time to appear as it is rendered on the fly.

The issue:

I want to display a popup message: "Please wait download initiated" when users click the download button. When the Internet Explorer download window appears, I want to disable the original popup.

Comment: I don't think you get any event, javascript or otherwise, when the download window appears AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Elad is true. But you can try one thing. If your are throwing content from page, then just before writing content do the stuffs you want